# How does an int variable change after being declared in a result of a statement as a double?

Tags: c, division, integer-division

Let us say you have 2 declared variables, each being an integer.

```
result = variable1 / variable2;
```

`result` is a double.

What would be the values of each of the variables after the previous statement executes? Let's say `variable1` is 10 and `variable2` is 6

Comment: Try it and show us what you get and what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You would get the result 10 / 6 = 1 (integer division). Then that result would be converted to a double and assigned to result. The variables would remain what they are, of course.

Comment: I see, it makes sense to me now. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing changes about `variable1` and `variable2`. They remain `int`s and hold their values.

Also, because both the operands of the divison are `int`s, the [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers) will take place.

The result of the integer division is (implicitly) converted to a `double` and stored into `result`.

Comment: Thank you this is what I thought initially I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

variable1 will continue to be 10, and variable2 will continue to be 6. The only expressions that change variables are assignment and compound-assignment expressions (`=`, `+=`, etc., and as a special shorthand `++` for `+= 1` and `--` for `-= 1`).

Comment: I see. I am reading into the assignments now. Thanks!